# Making Javascript IE-compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the below code to reload the CAPTCHA image on a page of mine whenever the page is reloaded (mainly for when people hit the back button to edit a two-page form). The code works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but does not function on IE (the CAPTCHA simply does not reload). How can I edit the code so that it works in IE? I don't know the differences between the browsers well enough to figure it out.

This is in IE 11, using jQuery 1.10.2. The console does not return any errors in any browser, IE included.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        Recaptcha.reload();
    });
})
```

Comment: Try using *only* `jQuery(document).ready` *OR* `jQuery(window).load`.  Don't nest them like that.

Comment: What does "does not function" mean?  Do you see any errors?  Have you tried any debugging?

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely forgot to put my debugging information in the post. It's now updated.

Comment: @StevenH: If you put a `console.log` before the `Recaptcha.reload` line, do you see it?  Does it work if you enter `Recaptcha.reload();` into the debug tool's console?  Have you tried my [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690489/making-javascript-ie-compatible#comment29246360_19690489)?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers (and by some, I mean IE in particular) don't like to execute `document.ready` when you hit the back button, so the code simply doesn't run.

Add this in your script and it *should* resolve the problem (it fixed similar issues for me)...

```
window.onunload = function () { };
```